# Does the Mobile Device Browsing File live on?

Tags: asp.net, mobile-browser

According to http://mdbf.codeplex.com/:

"Due to the organizational restructuring of the team that developed and supported the Mobile Device Browser file, we will no longer have the resources to support and update this CodePlex project. The team will be providing two more releases – one on the 27th July 2010 and the final release on the 24th August 2010. 
We would like to thank everyone who used our product over the past year and a half. We would also like to thank everyone who contributed to the discussions and raised issues on our data."

Does this project live on someplace else or is there an equivelent project?

Answer (score 0):

[51degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) claims to have a replacement, but it isn't made in the same way (via .browser definition files).

MDBF is still hosted on codeplex though - they reopened it by demand, but there isn't any promises of any updates that could occur.